# Measurable PNG image

Tags: png, ppi, measurement, units

I have a PNG image which is supposed to have a scale unit. Apparently there is an option in the png format to define a ppi or some similar concept. The goal is to be able to make physical measurement on the png image.

Does anyone know a tool where I extract/read/draw line to measures using such a png file ?

I tried paint, imageJ, inkscape but I haven't found such an option in any of these tool.

Comment: This all shows only a vague understanding of the problem being solved. If the image has, for instance, a picture of a rule or tape measure, then the only way to get that scale would be to set the image on your screen so that it matches a real measure. Trying to extrapolate any ppi measurement on a display of unknown quantity would be more likely to confuse than confirm.

Comment: There is actually a visible scale on the png image, and normally it was saved taking into this information. Are you saying there is no such feature in the png format to define a scale  ? I don't really get what does the resolution has to do with my problem.

Comment: Saving the image with a specific PPI doesn't guarantee it will be drawn at any given size on your screen.

Comment: Okay, but the ppi part was my guess and I may have got it wrong. There is well an extension for physical measurment in png, pHYs. If an image has such an extension, how can i make use of it with a software packet ?

Comment: YOu have to understand, that the ppi doesn't have anything to do with the size of the image. It defines the resolution. What you need is to change the unit for image size from pixel to your measurement unit (cm, inch or whatever) If the image itself is larger than the scale that is shown, the background needs to be respectively larger. Use the ruler if necessary (even paint has rulers)

Comment: `pHYs` defines only pixel aspect ratio. Without it, square pixels are assumed. There is nothing that can define actual size on screen; partly because computers completely ignore physical display size [even though they are nominally aware of it] & only consider resolution.

Comment: @Tetsujin be a bit careful a image can have two things called resolution. one is indeed the PPI, DPI whatever you have setting and other is number of pixels.

Comment: @joojaa - all I mean is that the computer only counts the number of pixels, it doesn't care about dot-pitch, other then to distinguish whether it will handle a display as 'retina' or 'normal. It cares not one bit whether that's on a 13" or a 34" display.

Comment: @Tetsujin i know you do. just pointing out that its a bit ambigious for noninitiated.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you actually have and what you want.

**I guess you have this:**

[image]

and you want to know the width, length and height of the metal gadget in the same photo.8

Answer: No direct way to tell the dimensions. Some heavy calculations are needed. If you know that the gadget is rectangular and the photo has been shot with high quality long focal length lens from so far away that there's no remarkable perspective nor lens inaccuracy distortions the calculations really can be done. But the amount of calculations is substantial.

By assuming the gadget is rectangular one can calculate the 3D space direction where the photo was shot from. Then one can (with trigonometry) decide how much the edges of the gadget are shortened when compared to the measurement tape.

In the image you can easily - for ex. by making a selection - see that one inch of the measurement tape is 213 pixels wide. Such measurement is possible in GIMP, Photoshop or other raster image editors. Illustrator, Inkscape etc vector programs do not show lengths as pixels of the opened photo. Unit px means there something else, probably pixels of maybe in the future rasterized drawing.

To measure the longest edge of the gadget you can draw for ex. a circular selection or a circle having the center in one corner and the curve in another. Here the circle is colored to red for clarity:

[image]

The circle diameter is 694 pixels. The radius is 347 pixels. That's the apparent length of the longest edge of the gadget. I skip measuring the angles in the gadget and assume it's rectangular and the view is isometric. The shortening can be compensated in isometric view by multiplying the apparent edge lengths with 1.22

The compensated length of the longest edge is 1.22 x 347 px i.e. 423 px.

One inch of the measurement tape took 213 pixels, so the longest edge of the gadget is 423/213 inches. That's 1.985 inches. The result is not exact, there can easily be one pixel error. Trying with 422/214 and 424/212 pixels one gets 1.97 and 2.00 inches. The truth is somewhere between them except the isometric view assumption and assuming there's no distortion caused by perspective nor the lens makes still everything guessing.

No trigonometry problem would exist if the measurement tape was placed in parallel with the wanted edge. The only calculation needed (still assuming there's no perspective nor lens distortion) is

- check how many image pixels corresponds one inch of the tape. Let it be N pixels.
- check how many pixels the wanted edge takes. Let it be M pixels.
- the edge length in inches is M/N.

Comment: Welcome. Your example does not actually work very well. Any measurement is only valid for the plane of the measurement And in your example the ruler is not on same plane otherwise your answer is ok. Just that your imsges are misleading.

Comment: As you see, the ruler is actually cylindrical, but the axis of the cylinder is in parallel with the image plane - I mean the camera sensor.  There's assumed to exist no perspective nor lens distortion and the projection of the gadget seems to be isometric. What's the actual error if those assumptions were true? I admit the angles between the gadget edges are only approximately 120 degrees. I said in the answer it would be much easier if the ruler were in parallel wit the interesting gadget edge.

Comment: so your using a telecentric lens. Ok, mention that it needs specal equipment for this to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is an object represented within the PNG containing **known** dimensions, it is **not possible** to extrapolate the physical size of objects shown in *any* PNG.

There is **no internal image data** that contains any physical scale or real world dimensions.

This is why, when physical scale is imperative, photographs are taken containing rulers, often photographic rulers as shown below, or known objects, such as coins

[image]

If the PNG shows *anything* which has *known* dimensions, then it is possible to *mathematically extrapolate* physical sizes of other objects in the PNG based upon the *scale of the known object* - however the PNG itself doesn't contain any such data internally.

Pixels *have no size* and are not a physical measurement. Therefor any resolution (PPI) is irrelevant in terms of real world measurements, size, or scale.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to take physical measurements from an image has 3 requirements:

- There is a known reference in the image
- There is no paralax in the image itself. So essentially this means one of the following:

  - Image was produced by a flatbed scanner.
  - Image was produced with a camera that had a telecentric lens.
  - Your viewing objects shadow (see comparators), some sort of rubbof or spraying residue.
  - original image was drawn (wtf is it doing as a png?)
  - You limit yourself to one plane and known dimension is on that plane. You can do this if you have a reasonable understanding on how to correct the paralax on said plane.
  - Swept electron microscope or something similarily exotic was used.
- you have a application that has a digital ruler and you have some way to calibrate said ruler.

Now if the two first are true then you can use any of the following.

Photoshop, Illustrator, Autocad, Creo, NX,Solidworks, Rhino... Probably inkscape works too you just have to scale the image first to match your calibration or convert by hand.

Note on PPI and scaling functions in images. they are not authoritative they are suggestions applications can follow them or not and they are subject to errors. PNG is especially problematic as it has a inbuilt system, but Adobe ignores this and sets it own so if the software that touched the png assumed photoshop was in play then the image might have 2 conflicting settings. Calibrate from image only way to be sure.

PS: if you need to measure in 3D then look into photogrametry, still need the ruler though.